# read single-precision use double precision variable in C

Tags: c, io

I have a text file containing single precision data, such as

```
 0.123456 0.123456 0.123456
```

I want to read it in C using following syntax:

```
 FILE *myfile.
 double c[4];
 int i=0;
 c[0]=1;
 myfile=fopen(...)
 for (i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    fscanf(myfile, "%lf", &c[i]);
    }
```

What I print is a huge number that is obviously wrong.
Any one can solve this problem?

Ps: I have edited my problems after I viewed the answers.
here is my more information:

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 FILE *file_params;
 int main() {
 double *delx;
 int i;
 file_params=fopen(filename,"r");
 delx = (double *) malloc ((4)*sizeof(double));
 delx[0]=0;
 for(i=1; i<=3; i++) fscanf(file_params, "%lf", &delx[i]);
 for(i=1; i<=3; i++) printf("%lf", delx[i]);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `lf%`, You meant `%lf`?

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything, and reads 3 values over the top of each other (so only the last one is left in the first element of the array, and the rest of the array is uninitialized.  Post an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I just wrote a sample. It doesn't work if I started the index from zero.

Comment: Your code (well, the version that I can see right now) does not print anything. Is it really so hard to include a short complete program that demonstrates the fault? Why do we have to try and guess what your code is? Your real problem is that you are rushing and not thinking straight. Slow down. Consider the problem. Think.

Comment: Looks like you completely changed your question.

Comment: wait - you just edited the code without any commentary about why you changed it.  The answers won't match the question unless you are clear about what you changed and what happened.

Comment: @AShelly Yeah, I deleted my comment and answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the rules. I found I needs to edit my problems after I tried your guy's suggestions.

Comment: So you have an _almost_ complete program here.  Make it a complete program, with a `main` and a print statement, and then post that along with the expected and actual results.  Then we can help.

Comment: Please please don't change the question drastically by removing the original question. By all means add more information in an edit, and perhaps ask a related follow-up, although that can be controversial. But the main lesson is to learn how to ask. For something like this you need an SSCCE. Had you supplied one you would have avoided all this pain.

Comment: Thanks, I will complete the program.

Comment: I posted the codes which are part of my project.

Comment: You don't seem to have any error checking for the call to `fopen`?

Comment: I don't have error. filename is the name of data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to the version of code that appears as I write ...

1. Remove `#include <windows.h>`
2. Change `filename` to be the name of a file that exists
3. Check that `file_params != NULL` and `delx != NULL` before proceeding
4. Check the return value of fscanf, e.g. `if ( 1 != fscanf(file_params, "%lf", &delx[i]) ) { printf("fscanf failed\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`
5. Change `printf("%lf",` to `printf("%f ",`

Program works.

> What I print is a huge number that is obviously wrong.

Possibly you are seeing the numbers all next to each other without spaces (since you didn't printf a space) and didn't realize what you were seeing.

Comment: -6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000...this is what I got from my code.

Comment: Please post *exactly* what you are compiling and running, and make sure that you are compiling and running what you posted. Use copy-paste. If you don't do this you are just wasting everybody's time. The code you have currently posted does not compile because `filename` is unrecognized. Even if you fix that, it could be that the file failed to open and you are printing junk out of memory instead.

Comment: I got the problem. I output the number out of the vector c. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes start at 0. You started at 1.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop should be

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    fscanf(myfile,"%lf",&c[i]);
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited my problem which is much closer to my case. I found the suggestion doesn't work. It is still very large.

Comment: Can you tell us the output you are getting?

Comment: dx=-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000......this is what I got from my code.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following errors:

1. Use `%lf` instead of `lf%`.
2. Use `&c[i]` instead of `&c`.
3. In the for- loop, use,

   ```
   for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   for (i=1;i<=3;i++) {
   ```

In summary,

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
    fscanf(myfile, "%lf", &c[i]);
    }
```